# Proof of Derivative of sin inverse $ sin^{-1} (x) $

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, inverse-function

Here are the first few lines of the proof:

$$   y = \sin^{-1} (x)$$
$$ x = \sin (y)$$
$$ \cos y(dy/dx) = 1$$
$$\vdots$$

Why is the $(dy/dx)$ retained in the third step? Isn't the derivative of sin $y = \cos x$ and hence shouldn't $(dy/dx)$ be omitted in the third step?

PS: I found this on several sources and so it isn't a typo.

Comment: Well, you see $y$ as a function of $x$, so you need to include $\frac{dy}{dx}$ by the chain rule.

Comment: It's simply the chain rule: $\frac d{dx} f(\cdot ) = f'(\cdot)\frac d{dx}(\cdot)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's chain rule.

You're treating $x$ as a function of $y$, $x = f(y)$. In this case, $f(y) = \sin y$.

So $\displaystyle \frac{d f(y)}{dx} = \frac{df(y)}{dy}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx} = \cos y \frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: Right. I didn't notice that. Thanks a lot everyone!!

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule states
$$ \frac{du(v(t))}{dx} = \frac{du}{dv}\frac{dv}{dx}
$$
When differentiating,
$$\begin{align*}
 \frac{d}{dx}x &= \frac{d}{dx} \sin y\\
 1 &= \frac{d\sin y}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} \\
 1 &= \cos y\,\frac{dy}{dx} \\
\end{align*}$$
In this case, $u = \sin y, v = y$.